# iPhone: WiFi, Bluetooth and cellular network not working

Tags: iphone, wifi, network, bluetooth

I have iPhone 3GS and suddenly it's gone away. I mean WiFi, bluetooth is not working, and I can't make any calls.

Here's a screenshot:

[image: No wifi, no BT, no network]

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: I would **guess** this has been IMEI blocked through the carrier.

Answer (score 1):

Wow. Seems like the modem/baseband part is gone wrong. Try rebooting the phone. If still not working - backup your information (from iTunes) and try a restore to factory settings (I'm assuming a factory unlocked phone, no JB). If this doesn't help - probably it's a hardware failure.

About the IMEI blockage - no, it's not the case.

Comment: Yeah, I have seen a firmware update go wrong and do this, and the actual hardware go wrong and do this, :(